# Using a target size (torch.Size([64, 1])) that is different to the input size (torch.Size([64, 20, 64])) incorrect results due to broadcasting

Tags: python, pytorch, lstm, loss, mse

First of all, I am playing around with Python/PyTorch/LSTM for no good reason. Just curious is all.
I "think" I have all of my tensors configured correctly.  My window size is 20.  My batch size is 64.

These are their shapes when I feed them to Dataset method.

```
    stock_train_tensor shape is:  torch.Size([4688, 20, 1])
    stock_validate_tensor shape is:  torch.Size([1172, 20, 1])
    stock_train_target_tensor shape is:  torch.Size([4688, 1])
    stock_validate_target_tensor shape is:  torch.Size([1172, 1])
```

My Dataset is:

```
    class StockPriceDataSet(Dataset):
        def __init__(self, data, targets):
            self.data = data
            self.targets = targets

        def __getitem__(self, index):
            x = self.data[index]
            y = self.targets[index]
            return x, y
     
        def __len__(self):
            return len(self.data)
```

Then I do this:

```
    training_dataset = StockPriceDataSet(stock_train_tensor, stock_train_target_tensor)
    validation_dataset= StockPriceDataSet(stock_validate_tensor, stock_validate_target_tensor)

    train_dataloader = DataLoader(training_dataset, batch_size=64, shuffle=False)
    validate_dataloader = DataLoader(validation_dataset, batch_size=64, shuffle=False)
```

My LSTM model is configured as such.

```
    lstm = nn.LSTM(input_size=1,  hidden_size=64, num_layers=2, batch_first=True)
    criterion = nn.MSELoss()
    optimizer = optim.SGD(lstm.parameters(),lr=0.01\])
```

And then when I try train the model:

```
    for epoch in range(config\["training"\]\["num_epoch"\]):
        for i, (x, y) in enumerate(train_dataloader):
            output, \_= lstm(x)
            y = y.float()
            time.sleep(6)
            #compute the loss and backpropogate
            loss = criterion(output, y) <===== this causes the warning
```

I get this warning:

```
loss.py:536: UserWarning: Using a target size (torch.Size([64, 1])) that is different to the input size (torch.Size([64, 20, 64])). This will likely lead to incorrect results due to broadcasting. Please ensure they have the same size.
```

I put some debug print statements and this is what I see right before the warning message.

```
output is shape:  torch.Size([64, 20, 64])
y is shape:  torch.Size([64, 1])
```

I tried repeating the target value across dim=1 so that my target tensor was also 64,20.  That resulted in the same message.

```
loss.py:536: UserWarning: Using a target size (torch.Size([64, 20])) that is different to the input size (torch.Size([64, 20, 64])). This will likely lead to incorrect results due to broadcasting. Please ensure they have the same size.
```

And, I tried to add a third dimension and got this:

```
loss.py:536: UserWarning: Using a target size (torch.Size([64, 20, 1])) that is different to the input size (torch.Size([64, 20, 64])). This will likely lead to incorrect results due to broadcasting. Please ensure they have the same size.
```

Any clue on how to debug this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

George

Comment: I just figured out that the torch.nn.LSTM module uses hidden_size (hidden_size * 1 or 2 if bidirectional) to set the 3rd dimension of the output tensor.  So in my case, it is always reformatting my input to 64, 20, 64.   I just found a bit in the docs that say "unless proj_size > 0".  I'm trying that now.

At least I've changed the warning message.

rnn.py:812: UserWarning: LSTM with projections is not supported with oneDNN. Using default implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to compare the outputs of one LSTM layer with labels without formatting it into a correct shape. You can either add a fully-connected layer to obtain correct shaped output from the pooled/flattened output of LSTM or only use the last output of LSTM layer for prediction. You can grasp the meanings of the outputs of LSTM [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/405163/what-is-the-output-of-an-lstm).

**Use Last Output of LSTM in Training**

```
for epoch in range(config\["training"\]\["num_epoch"\]):
    for i, (x, y) in enumerate(train_dataloader):
        output, \_= lstm(x)
        y = y.float()
        time.sleep(6)
        #compute the loss and backpropogate
        loss = criterion(output[:, :, -1], y) # using the last output from LSTM
```

**Using LSTM with Fully Connected Layers with Flattening/Pooling**

```
class LSTM_Model_w_Flat(nn.Module):
    """ LSTM model that uses flattened outputs to feed into fully-connected layers.
    """
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.use_pooling = use_pooling
        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(input_size=1,  hidden_size=64, num_layers=2, batch_first=True) # same as LSTM being used
        self.flat = nn.Flatten()
        # fully-connected layer
        self.dense = nn.Linear(64*20, 1) # the output from LSTM [64, 20, 64] becomes [64, 20*64] after flattening

    def forward(self, x):
        x, *_ = self.lstm(x)
        x = self.flat(x)
        x = self.dense(x)

class LSTM_Model_w_Pooling(nn.Module):
    """ LSTM model that uses average-pooled outputs to feed into fully-connected layers.
    """
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.use_pooling = use_pooling
        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(input_size=1,  hidden_size=64, num_layers=2, batch_first=True) # same as LSTM being used
        # fully-connected layer
        self.dense = nn.Linear(20, 1) # the output from LSTM [64, 20, 64] becomes [64, 20] after pooling

    def forward(self, x):
        x, *_ = self.lstm(x)
        x = torch.mean(x, dim=-1)
        x = self.dense(x)
```

Then, your training loop will be

```
model = LSTM_Model_w_Flat() # LSTM_Model_w_Pooling() for pooling usage
for epoch in range(config\["training"\]\["num_epoch"\]):
    for i, (x, y) in enumerate(train_dataloader):
        output = model(x)
        y = y.float()
        time.sleep(6)
        #compute the loss and backpropogate
        loss = criterion(output, y)
```